# How to pass props using Redux connect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Im trying to pass strings and a child component using redux props as follows below. I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property circularImage of undefined"

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native'

// CircularImage.js
function CircularImage () {
  return (
    <Image source={this.props.imageSourceUrl} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} /> // Rounded Img
  )
}
CircularImage.propTypes = {
  imageSourceUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps1(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    imageSourceUrl: require('../images/icon.png')
  }
}

CircularImage = connect(mapStateToProps1)(CircularImage);

// ScreenHeaderWithImage.js
function ScreenHeaderWithImage () {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 50}}>
      <View style={{marginBottom: 50}}>
        {this.props.circularImage}
      </View>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{this.props.primaryHeadline}</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{this.props.secondaryHeadline}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
ScreenHeaderWithImage.propTypes = {
  primaryHeadline: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  secondaryHeadline: PropTypes.string, // Optional
}

function mapStateToProps2(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    primaryHeadline: 'Timothy Max',
    secondaryHeadline: 'Kenya',
    circularImage: CircularImage
  }
}

ScreenHeaderWithImage = connect(mapStateToProps2)(ScreenHeaderWithImage);

export default ScreenHeaderWithImage
```

Comment: You can refactor functional components into classes then you can refer to props as this.props. Or just pass props explicitly as an argument and refer to them as props.

Comment: See the snack https://snack.expo.io/@techytimo/redux-props-example

Comment: Try to add reducers and get your data from the store.

Answer (score 2):

When using a function component the function should receive the props as parameters. Like this

```
function ScreenHeaderWithImage (props) {
   ...
   <View style={{marginBottom: 50}}>
    {props.circularImage}
   </View>
   ....
}
```

Comment: This seems to be taking me closer to the solution. I am now passing "props" on both components. Problem is that the circularImage is not getting displayed and I get the warning "Functions are not valid as React child"

Comment: You can invoke the function circularImage() (and pass any arguments you might need)

Comment: I tried that... I get the error "Cannot call a class as a function"

Comment: Have you changed CircularImage to a class ?

Comment: Yes. Extending Component. But that yields the same error "Cannot call a class as a function"

Comment: Change it back to a function.

Answer (score 1):

try extending from component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Image } from 'react-native'

class CircularImage extends Component {   
  return (
    <Image source={this.props.imageSourceUrl} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} /> // Rounded Img
  )
}
CircularImage.propTypes = {
  imageSourceUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    imageSourceUrl: require('../images/icon.png')
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(CircularImage);
```

it gets clearer on what you are trying to accomplish

Anyway in this case you don't need mapStateToProps because you don't have any props depending on state (if you are planning to pass imageSourceUrl as a prop by 
You can simply export CircularImage without connecting it

this is probably what you need:

**CircularImage:**

```
export default class CircularImage extends Component {   
  return (
    <Image source={this.props.imageSourceUrl} style={{width: 100, height: 100}} /> // Rounded Img
  )
}
CircularImage.propTypes = {
  imageSourceUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

**ScreenHeaderWithImage:**

```
export default class ScreenHeaderWithImage extends Component {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 50}}>
      <View style={{marginBottom: 50}}>
        <CircularImage imageSourceUrl={require('../images/icon.png')}
      </View>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{this.props.primaryHeadline}</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{this.props.secondaryHeadline}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
ScreenHeaderWithImage.propTypes = {
  primaryHeadline: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  secondaryHeadline: PropTypes.string, // Optional
}
```

You don't have props depending on state in ScreenHeaderWithImage as well, so you don't need to connect it

Just pass them down to the element when you use it

Comment: Good solution but Im trying to use functions only and pass the CircularImage either as a prop or through redux compose or connect

Comment: I haven't tested it, but passing "circularImage: <CircularImage />" to your mapStateToProps2 should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change a number of things:

1. Pass "props" as an argument to both functional components
2. Change the image propType

On the ScreenHeaderWithImage component:

3. Add a proptype for the circularImage component
4. Map this prop as a function that returns the component
5. Invoke the function

See the comments in the code below:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native'

// CircularImage.js
function CircularImage (props) { // 1.
  return (
    <Image source={ props.imageSourceUrl } style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} /> 
  )
}
CircularImage.propTypes = {
  imageSourceUrl: Image.propTypes.source // 2.
}

function mapStateToProps1() {
  return {
    imageSourceUrl: require('../images/icon.png')
  }
}

CircularImage = connect(mapStateToProps1)(CircularImage);

// ScreenHeaderWithImage.js
function ScreenHeaderWithImage (props) { // 1.
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 50}}>
      <View style={{marginBottom: 50}}>
        { props.circularImage() /* 5. */ } 
      </View>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{ props.primaryHeadline }</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>{ props.secondaryHeadline }</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
ScreenHeaderWithImage.propTypes = {
  primaryHeadline: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  secondaryHeadline: PropTypes.string, 
  circularImage: PropTypes.func.isRequired, // 3.
}

function mapStateToProps2() {
  return {
    primaryHeadline: 'Timothy Max',
    secondaryHeadline: 'Kenya',
    circularImage: () => <CircularImage /> // 4.
  }
}

ScreenHeaderWithImage = connect(mapStateToProps2)(ScreenHeaderWithImage);

export default ScreenHeaderWithImage
```